# Removing duplicates from array using on visualforce component

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist, unique

I want to remove duplicates from final array showing on my visualforce page .

**Actual Working code :**(I am getting duplicates in array)

```
                function(result, event){

                     //if success
                    if(event.status){

                    var data = {results: []}
                    data.results = result;   
                    query.callback(data);             


                    }
                     else{
                          alert('Invalid Field/Object API Name : '+event.message);
                     }

                 }, 
                  {escape: true}
            );
        }
```

**Example Code I took for change :**

```
function unique(list){
var result = [];
$.each(list, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
  });
  return result;
}
```

**Work All Around for result :**

```
     if(event.status){ 
     var result = [];
     var data = {results: []}
     $.each(list, function(i, e) {
     if ($.inArray(e, data.results) == -1)                    data.results.push(e);
   });
    data.results = result;                            
    query.callback( data);                           
    }
```

But i cant able to get result .Please help me to make this work.Please let me know if my question is unclear.

Updated original code

Comment: https://github.com/mikolalysenko/uniq/blob/master/uniq.js from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniq#why-use-this-instead-of-underscoreunique)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, you just forgot to remove the `data.results = result` line, that prevent you from getting the correct result:

```
var result = [];
var data = {results: []}

$.each(list, function(i, e) {
  if ($.inArray(e, data.results) == -1)
    data.results.push(e);
});

// You have to comment the following line, or data.result get reset
// You could also push to result instead of data.results
// in the $.each function above

//data.results = result;                            
// ...                           
console.log(data.results) // => data.results has unique elements!
```

You could also use the [reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
data.results = list.reduce(function(ar,item) {
  if(result.indexOf(item) == -1)
    ar.push(item)
  return ar
}, result)
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3Lphbfa/)

Comment: have you  tried using the reduce method? There is a `list` variable in your `$.inArray` call, are you sure this variable exists and you have not switched it with `result`? Have you added some `console.log()` statements to debug your code?